# UV mapping issues while loading collada model exported with Sketchup

Tags: three.js, collada, sketchup

I load collada models, exported via Google Sketchup, into my Three.js (v63) scene with the Three.js collada loader.

The models are loaded, but with some, textures aren't well mapped,  like in the following picture :
[image: texture mapping issue]

My first question is how to detect this kind of problems and then, is there a way to leverage the exported UVs from sketchup to correctly map the textures ?

The model from the sceenshot comes from : http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=557d5f1b5a076bdcf53b1b21212345ca&prevstart=0